# Trying to install the maxmind geolite2 database

Tags: php, maxmind

I'm having a bit of trouble installing this. I have a managed VPS and my support said they installed it, here is the error that is coming up when I try using the script:

"Warning: require(/home/SITE/public_html/SITE.info/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/SITE/public_html/SITE.info/age1/age1.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/SITE/public_html/SITE.info/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/SITE/public_html/SITE.info/age1/age1.php on line 3"

Any help on this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "MaxMind": "src/" }
```

Add this script in your composer.json file and do install composer and dependencies again.